# test a function using assert c++

Tags: c++, try-catch, assert, throw, greatest-common-divisor

I want to test the gcd function using assertions, but I don't know how to catch the exception(and prevent the program from crashing).

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
if(a<0 || b<0) {
    throw "Illegal argument";
}
if(a==0 || b==0)
    return a+b;
while(a!=b) {
    if(a>b) {
        a = a - b;
    }
    else {
        b = b - a;
    }
}
return a;
```

}

```
void test_gcd() {
assert(gcd(16,24) == 8);
assert(gcd(0, 19) == 19);
try {
    gcd(5, -15);
    assert(false);
} catch (char* s) {
    assert(true);
    cout << "Illegal";
}
```

}

Comment: `assert` does not throw exceptions, it just terminates the program after printing out some stuff.

Comment: Also you should rather use `throw` with something that derives from `std::exception`, rather using a `const char*` literal.

Comment: `assert(true)` is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > *"I want to test the gcd function using assertions, but I don't know **how to catch the exception** (and prevent the program from crashing)."*

As stated in the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert) `assert()` is an implementation defined macro (emphasis mine):

> ```
> #ifdef NDEBUG
> #define assert(condition) ((void)0)
> #else
> #define assert(condition) /*implementation defined*/
> #endif
> ```
>
> If `NDEBUG` is not defined, then `assert` checks if its argument (which must have scalar type) compares equal to zero. If it does, assert outputs implementation-specific diagnostic information on the standard error output ***and calls `std::abort`***. The diagnostic information is required to include the text of expression, as well as the values of the standard macros `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, and the standard variable `__func__`.

Thus ***`assert()` doesn't throw an exception*** you can catch. To test your code and correct usage of exceptions you should have something like the following, where `expect_true()` is something that prints a message, if the parameter evaluates to `false` and doesn't `abort()` your program:

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if(a<0 || b<0) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("a and b must be negative values");
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

```
#define expect_true(arg) \
        do { \
            if(!(arg)) { \
                std::cout << "Unexpected false at " \
                          << __FILE__ << ", " << __LINE__ << ", " << __func__ << ": " \
                          << #arg \
                          << std::endl; } \
        } while(false);

void test_gcd() {
    expect_true(gcd(16,24) == 8);
    expect_true(gcd(0, 19) == 19);
    bool exceptionCaught = false;
    try {
        gcd(5, -15);
    } catch (const std::invalid_argument& ex) {
        cout << "Illegal as expected" << endl;
        exceptionCaught = true;
    }
    expect_true(exceptionCaught);
}
```

Here's a [fully working version](http://ideone.com/M5kWz3). And [another sample](http://ideone.com/OCjiLZ) failing the test case.

---

Also since `assert()` will always abort your `test_gcd()` function, that's a bit tedious way to do unit testing. I'd recommend using a decent unit testing framework, where you have more control over testing expectations and running various test cases. E.g. use something like [Google Test](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer) (which will have an implementation for `EXPECT_TRUE()`).